# How can I create a separate namespace within a Python script?

Tags: python

I would like to store a bunch of variables under a Python namespace without creating a separate module. I notice that the result of `ArgumentParser`'s `parse_args()` is a `argparse.Namespace` object. You can access the arguments through dot-syntax.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
# some arg definitions here...
args = parser.parse_args()  # returns a `argparse.Namespace` object
```

How can I create the equivalent of an `argparse.Namespace`? I know I can do something similar with a `dict` but I would like to use dot-syntax. Is there any built-in class that just lets you assign arbitrary attributes?

Comment: How about `class Namespace(object): pass`? Instantiate it, then just start assigning attributes.

Comment: *Is there any built-in class that just lets you assign arbitrary attributes?* - instances of *any* Python class that doesn't define `__slots__` will let you assign arbitrary attributes. (That's the principle behind @dano's and @Bakuriu's suggestion of just using a class).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting with python3.3 you can use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace).

However an alternative is simply:

```
class Namespace(object):
    pass

namespaceA = Namespace()
namespaceA.x = 1
```

The full code for `SimpleNamespace` isn't much longer.

---

Note that you cannot simply use an `object` instance:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> o.x = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'x'
```

This is because instances of `object` do not have a `__dict__` attribute:

```
>>> vars(object())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Which means you cannot set the attributes of an instance of `object`.

Any `object` subclass that does not have the [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#slots) attribute set *does* have the `__dict__` which is used (by default) to store/retrieve attributes:

```
>>> class Namespace(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> a = Namespace()
>>> a.x = 1     # same as as.__dict__['a'] = 1
>>> a.__dict__
{'x': 1}
```

For further information about attribute setting/lookup you should learn about [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about `types.SimpleNamespace`, and it makes the intention clear

Comment: Great answer. I'm a little confused about something though-- why is it that I can assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of a new class that inherits from `object`, but not to an instance of `object`?

Comment: @Sean: Because `object` instances have no `__dict__` in which to store new arbitrary attributes.

Comment: Bakuriu: If you changed your answer to `class Namespace(object):` it would work in both Python 2 and 3...

Comment: @martineau The answer written as-is actually works in Python 2 (or Python 2.7.7, at least)-- apparently you don't need a new style class for this, so I think the last line of the answer should be removed.

Comment: @SeanMackesey It works, but there are reason to avoid old-style classes, so, since it doesn't cost anything, you should always inherit from `object` in python2. I've decided to follow martineau advice and simply change the code myself (although I use only python3 currently). I also expanded a bit with regard to your observation about `object`.

Answer (score 2):

A class can be used as a namespace, where the variables are class members:

```
class Namespace1:
    foo = 'a'
    bar = 5
```

To prevent callers from trying to instantiate, you can use a baseclass like:

```
class objectless(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError('%s should not be instantiated' % cls)
```

And use it like:

```
class Namespace1(objectless):
    ...
```

Comment: Personally I think that overloading a class definition like this wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @martineau can you explain why?

Comment: Mainly because it's defining a weird class that can't be instantiated and is unnecessary given that there's a standard way to do such a thing in Python, namely by a defining a module, which doesn't require any tricky class definitions and is more explicit. There are other issues, like defining a regular function in this type of namespace would require using a `@staticmethod` decorator to prevent a `TypeError: unbound method func() must be called with Namespace1 instance as first argument` when calling it outside of the class definition via a `Namespace1.func()` (the most likely usage)

Comment: **There are substantial benefits to reusing class rather than module machinery.** Even in 2021, modules *still* only offer a fraction of the dunder methods available to classes – and even less for packages supporting all Python versions that have yet to hit EOL. Moreover, anyone opposed to "defining a weird class" should avoid importing anything from the standard library; most classes defined by the standard library are *very* weird and magical. That's okay, because "weird and magical" also means useful, succinct, and automated (e.g., `enum.Enum`, `abc.ABCMeta`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want "the equivalent of an `argparse.Namespace`", use `argparse.Namespace`:

```
from argparse import Namespace

ns = Namespace(a=1)
print ns.a
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a python `class`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Depending on what you want exactly, you can define a bunch of variables as attributes of a class (either a variable of an instance or of the class itself) and access them that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to dynamically add attributes to it.  For example, a class parses command-line flags you access them directly like args.verbose, right?  If so, you may be thinking of setattr() that lets you add arbitrary attributes.

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

foo = Foo()
setattr(foo, 'ack', 'bar')
print(foo.ack) # prints 'bar'
```