# How to disable class instantiation in Python?

Tags: class, python-3.x

Sometimes I create a class and its only used to store some values or static methods and I **never** want to create an instance.

Is there some way to express this in Python3?

Eg:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print("world")

    # is there a better way to do this?
    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception("instantiation isnt supported for this class!")

# OK
MyClass.hello()

# NOT OK
c = MyClass()
```

Comment: Why put these in a class, rather than put the values and functions into a separate script and `import` it?

Comment: Sure, mostly this is better, sometimes I make standalone scripts and its convenient to group functions like this (its also possible to use subclassing and class methods, in that case you would still want to use a class instead of a module).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `objectless` baseclass found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896393/2096752) (which is actually an answer to a different question).

```
class objectless:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError('%s should not be instantiated' % cls)

class UninstantiateableClass(objectless):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return 'bar'
    ...
```

Note that in python2, `objectless` should explicitly subclass `object`, in order to be a new-style class.

Comment: Why should `objectclass` be a subclass of `object`? (in Python3)

Comment: It doesn't have to, it's just a python2 habit.